# Stop directory listing using .htaccess and redirect to good error page

Tags: apache, htaccess, error, gui

I have a directory with several sub directories. I found this article [Preventing Directory Listing](http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/htaccess11.shtml) that shows me how to prevent people from getting the directory listings.

```
IndexIgnore *
```

But it produces a bad error page, (it looks like an empty directory listing). Instead I would like to redirect the user to a page or show a better error page when they try to view the directory listings of a sub directory.

I am using Apache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Options -Indexes
ErrorDocument 403 /path/to/403.html
```

Comment: I get a 403 error. I checked that my 403.html document exists and is publicly available. I also used the full path. 

     'Forbidden
      You don't have permission to access /files/2011/ on this server.
      Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.'

Comment: Read server's logs for 500 error description. Can also show relevant part of config

Comment: If you get a 500 error then it suggests the error document is not "publicly available" and you probably have a conflict with existing directives in your `.htaccess` file. The error documents need to be accessible without restriction - this will sometimes mean adding additional _conditions_ to your `.htaccess` file (or server config) to make this so.