# HTTP code 403, access denied & Options -Indexes

Tags: htaccess, http, authentication, error, code

at "webmasters.stackexchange.com" I already found a similar topic: 
[Stop directory listing using .htaccess and redirect to good error page](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/21402/stop-directory-listing-using-htaccess-and-redirect-to-good-error-page)

```
Options -Indexes
ErrorDocument 403 /path/to/403.html
```

However, now I want to distinguish between whether there was actaully a directory listing request issued OR if the user tried to access a protected area (through htaccess) unsuccessfully.

Both fire a 403, now how do I know which was the reason (the directory listing or the htaccess AuthName... thing) ?

Comment: I am not sure you can without mod_perl. I can't think of anything yet.

Comment: What do you want to do if it was a directory request OR protected area? Any reason why you can't check this in your 403 document itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally it worked by putting an additional line in the .**htacces** of the protected folder (call it `private`)

```
ErrorDocument 403 /forbidden-because-of-protection
```

and in the **root's .htaccess** I put the line like

```
ErrorDocument 403 /forbidden-because-of-directory-listing
```

So now when there is some request issued like `/private/some/thing/bla` the first .htaccess rule will be called - thus redirecting to `/forbidden-because-of-protection` otherwise like requesting a directory listing (thus not in `/private`) apache goes for the second rule.

Answer (score 1):

A request for a directory listing will have a URL that ends in `/`.

So `http://example.com/images/` will be a 403 because of the directory listing.

`http://example.com/private/document.html` will be a 403 because of your rule for the private directory.

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't work with my situation as I have a folder called like "private" that is protected but there is an index file in there, so requesting that file could be done via "http://example.com/private/" which has a trailing slash NOT because of the directory listing but because of the .htaccess protection.